# Using ClipboardSetData function to set the contents of the clipboard of the remote machine

Tags: c++, c, freerdp

I've been tasked with sending text clipboard data to a WfreeRDP connected remote machine's clipboard from a web application and am having trouble knowing where to look.

`WFreeRDP` has a TestClipboardFormats.c which kind of looks like what I need and features a `SetClipboardData` and `GetClipboardData` which I've managed to get working (according to the Debug console output at least)

```
BOOL bSuccess;
UINT32 SrcSize;
UINT32 DstSize;

const char* pSrcData = commandArgs.c_str();

char* pDstData;

textHtmlStringFormatId = ClipboardRegisterFormat(clipboard, "CF_TEXT");
utf8StringFormatId = ClipboardRegisterFormat(clipboard, "UTF8_STRING");

SrcSize = (UINT32)(strlen(pSrcData) + 1);

bSuccess = ClipboardSetData(clipboard, textHtmlStringFormatId, pSrcData, SrcSize);

fprintf(stderr, "ClipboardSetData: %d\n", bSuccess);

DstSize = 0;

pDstData = (char*)ClipboardGetData(clipboard, textHtmlStringFormatId, &DstSize);

fprintf(stderr, "ClipboardGetData: %s\n", pDstData);

free(pDstData);
```

I was kind of hoping the remote machine's clipboard would be populated with the data I'd sent as it can be retrieved with `GetClipboardData` successfully, but right clicking on the remote machine yields no results.

Am I using the right method? Or maybe using it incorrectly?